# process to create git merge report to show pending merges on a release

Tags: git, merge

I have git release branches like july19,aug19,sep19 .Developers create their own branch from  a release they want to work on and commit their changes. I need to find the branches those are pending to be merged back to the release branch from which they branched their temporary development branch and all future branches.

For example: if two developers created branch1, branch2 for their development work from release/july19  did some code and didnot merge it yet.

I need a report to find pending merge from developer branch to:

july19 (parent branch from developer created a branch)
aug19 (future release)
sep19 (future release)

New to git. Trying to migrate to git from svn. Development strategy is master->develop->release branches

I tried `git branch --no-merged options` in july19 clone dir  to see if it would display the list of branches pending merges to this branch, expecting branch1, branch2 would show up, but it displayed none?

```
cd july19:
git branch --no-merged options
result:none
```

Comment: Remember that unlike SVN, Git is *distributed*. If some developer (let's call him Bob) created a branch named `branch1`, that only means that *Bob* has a thing named `branch1` in *Bob's* repository. Your repository is unaffected. You can't even see his branch, much less make any determination about whether something is merged. The switch from centralized repo (SVN) to distributed (Git, Mercurial) is bad enough, and Git makes it worse: in Mercurial, everyone shares branch names, but in Git, they're all *private*.

Comment: What this means is: first, Bob has to contact some other Git. You might dedicate one system to holding the Git repository that you, Bob, and everyone else will treat *as if* it were a centralized repo. (You could even host this pseudo-central repo on GitHub or Bitbucket or some web hosting site, if you like.) Then Bob, and other developers too, will have *their* Git call up this central Git and ask it to take their commits and set *its* branch names based on their branch names. [continued]

Comment: Now, at this point, *you* can have *your* Git call up this central-by-cooperation server, and get from it, *its* list of branch names, as updated by Alice, Bob, Carol, and so on. *Your* Git won't call these *branches* though. Your Git will refer to them as your *remote-tracking names:* what was `X` is now `origin/X`. You can then check with `git branch -r --merged` or `git branch -r --no-merged`, with the `-r` meaning: *tell me about my remote-tracking names, not my branch names.*

Comment: git branch -r --no-merged works !Thanks ! But it did show all branches subbranching from anywhere .I donot want aug19 sub branches showing up in july19 no merged list .Nor am I a able to find direct parent from a branch name .

Comment: Git does not have any kind of branch hierarchy: each branch *name* contains the hash ID of one (1) commit, and that's it. Commits are *contained in* a branch if they are *reachable from* that particular (temporarily-named) commit. Git adds a *new* commit to the branch by adding a commit whose parent is the old branch-tip, then changing the *name* to point to the new commit. See also http://think-like-a-git.net/

Comment: Note too that multiple names can all identify one particular commit: that commit is on *all* of those branches, at the same time. You can add and delete branch names at any time, and the set of branches that some commit is "on" changes. The test: "is X merged into Y" just means: does X point specifically *to* a commit that, if I start at commit Y and work backwards, I can get to X? Using `git branch --merged` tests all *other* X's for some particular given Y.